# Want to assert a text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to assert a value appearing in the text field.The id of the text field is blNo. I am not able to use a proper assert.Looking for some suggestions.

Comment: are you able to extract that value?? your question is incomplete... do you have prerequisite data from which you want to compare the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [assertTrue](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue)

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("blNo")).getText();
assertTrue("The text doesn't contains the value", text.contains("value"));
```

The message will appear in case the `assert` failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Testng along with Selenium. I also was having an issue implementing Selenium's assert, so this is what I created. Constructive feedback is welcomed.

Retrieve the the text via `getText()` against your WebElement object.

```
WebElement object = driver.findElement(By.id("blNo"));
String text = object.getText();
```

Then send the WebElement object to a method like the `AreEqual` method below.

```
public class Assert 
{ 

    public static void AreEqual(String comparethis, String tothis, String falseMsg)
    {

        try
        {
            Log.Info("Compare this object: " + comparethis);
            Log.Info("     to this object: " + tothis);
            if(comparethis.equals(tothis))
            {
                Log.Info(comparethis + " is equal to " + tothis);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info(comparethis + " is not equal to " + tothis);
                Fail();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("[EXCEPTION CAUGHT] : Assert.AreEqual() | " + falseMsg + "  | Exception: " + e);
            throw(e);
        }

    }// AreEqual method

}// Assert Class
```

Fail method

```
public static void Fail()
{
    org.testng.Assert.fail("[TEST FAILED]");
    Log.Error("[TEST FAILED] : Assert.Fail()");
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
Assert.assertEquals("Expected Text",driver.findElement(By.id("blNo")).getText());
```